# Why it's better to use double floating point precision instead of single point precision for gradient check

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I came across the following," A common pitfall is using single precision floating point to compute gradient check. It is often that case that you might get high relative errors (as high as 1e-2) even with a correct gradient implementation. In my experience I’ve sometimes seen my relative errors plummet from 1e-2 to 1e-8 by switching to double precision." Not sure why it's better to use double precision? If gradients fall between 1e-2 to 1e-8, then single floating point precision can cover even smaller values than this, so not sure where is the problem?

Comment: I can't answer precisely, but the general limitation of any fixed-size representation of real numbers is due to the accumulation of errors: after a sequence of many operations, each operation approximating the result by a little bit, the result can be very far from the true result.

Comment: @Erwan. Thank you. So less precision will approximate to a larger gradient values even by little fraction. This on the long run will cause accumulation of errors if I understand you correctly please?

Comment: Yes, this is the general problem as far as I know.